# I face to error like this : cannot change value of locked binding for '*tmp*'

Tags: r, compare, data-analysis, categorical-data

I try to create new binary variable for income, where 1 indicates people who are rich and 0 indicates people who are poor.
But I face error like this:

> Error in dat$income2[dat$income <- 1] <- "rich" :
> cannot change value of locked binding for '*tmp*

```
dat$income2 <- NA

dat$income2[dat$income <- 1] <- "rich"
dat$income2[dat$income <- 0] <- "poor"
```

Comment: Change the assignment `<-` in `dat$income <- 1` to `==`. And the same for the other instruction. Vote to close as simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

The code in brackets should be a logical expression not an assignment. Change `dat$income <- 1` to `dat$income == 1` and it will work.

```
dat <- data.frame(income = c(0, 1, 0, 1))

dat$income2 <- NA

dat$income2[dat$income == 1] <- "rich"
dat$income2[dat$income == 0] <- "poor"

dat

  income income2
1      0    poor
2      1    rich
3      0    poor
4      1    rich
```

Comment: Please go ahead and accept. This will also let everyone know that you found a solution -- Thanks!